# VSTS build definition using npm task for angular cli build - where's the output?

Tags: angular, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I've created a build definition in Visual Studio Team Services with a hosted agent, and I'm *trying* to build an Angular 4 project via an npm task, but when I use a Copy File or Publish Artifact task, the places I look for output are always empty.  The npm task looks like this:

```
Version: 1.*
Command: custom
Working folder with package.json: $/teamproj/soln/proj
Command and arguments: run vsts-build-dev -op $(BuildArtifactStagingDirectory)\wwwroot
```

I've tried controlling the output and retrieving the compiled code via a number of methods...the npm step usually *completes*, but I'm never able to find the output.  Currently I have a custom function called "vsts-build-dev" which just runs "ng build -dev".  I wasn't sure whether I could build directly to a subfolder of the BuildArtifactStagingDirectory...the npm task works, but a later zip of the build files is empty.

The logs don't always give the full picture of where the files are being generated and I've found debugging these tedious as they're always taking 6-10 minutes before failing...what's the best way to troubleshoot file paths with a hosted agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is: `npm run <command> [-- <args>]`

For example, Command and arguments: `run vsts-build-dev -- -op ..\a\wwwroot`. (can’t use build variable, using relative path instead)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, the BuildArtifactStagingDirectory is still empty...is the output path relative to the npm runtime, or the working directory that's being compiled (which is something like **d:\a\4\s\teamproj\soln\proj**)?

Comment: It is related to the project.json path, so using `run vsts-build-dev -- -op ..\..\..\..\a\wwwroot`

Comment: Yes, actually the underlying problem was also related to a hard-coded -outdir argument in the .angular-cli.json file which was overriding this, but your solution helped me get there.